# Google Street View API seamless

Tags: api, view, unity-game-engine, google-street-view

I try to collect the geosphere, using 6 images of streets from different angles, namely:

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?" + "Size =" + 1024 + "x" + 1024 + "& location =" + latitude + "," + longitude + "& heading =" + heading + "& pitch =" + 0 + "& fov =" + 90 + "& sensor = false "
```

where heading takes values 0,90,180,270 degrees. However, these images are not sewn together (example attached).

Picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmsw2z8g7jd0cnv/seams.jpg?dl=0

I understand that this is due to the slope of the geo-camera relative to the horizon.

However, if the query image in place of crosslinking, i.e. heading = 45 degrees, the discontinuity is not seen, then the server Google account for calculating the tilt of the camera with a single image, but somehow alters the rendering camera tilt.

How can I be if the only possible way to get the picture - this html request and javascript methods are not suitable for my application?

Comment: do you still needs answer for this?

Answer (score -1):

use this asset
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28512

It converts Google Street View URL into Unity3D cubemap